# Memory integrity of C# applications (XNA)

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, xna, xna-4.0

Recently, I realized that the memory stored in XNA's RenderTarget2D datastructures may be lost on various (somewhat unpredictable) occasions (Screen lock, Moving the application window over to a second screen etc.). In this case the problem can be avoided by checking IsContentLost() before drawing.

However, I noticed that other parts of allocated memory (e.g. large bit fields) in my XNA application also can get lost in similar situations. Could this be garbage collection gone wrong? Are there other flags like "IsContentLost()" that needed to be checked in order to make sure all allocated memory is safely kept in C# applications (XNA specifically)?

Comment: .NET-allocated memory should never become corrupted. If it is, that's either a bug in your code, the .NET runtime, or your RAM hardware. The memory allocated on the GPU can become lost, as you've noticed -- this is normal. Can you provide more information?

Comment: I believe that `IsContentLost` is about GPU memory being reused. This is completely unrelated to .NET memory management in general and is not handled by .NET GC.